# Dupe hammer: multiple tags, multiple gold badges

Tags: support, tags, dupehammer

[image]

I dupe-hammered a question tagged with [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) which hasn't been edited; tags were added by the OP. I have both gold badges, however, I have more votes on [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) plus I acquired it before [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

This could be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); nevertheless, I would like to know why [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) was chosen over [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile)?

Edit:

- [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) awarded in March, 2014. Total votes: 1965
- [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) awarded in January, 2015. Total votes: 1195

Edit:

Just to clarify my question, is there a specific criteria behind it or is it a random behavior?

Comment: It looks like the tag with more questions/higher traffic is picked.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no. I have edited my question to reflect date of awarding each tag as well as total votes.

Comment: My guess would be alphabetic order rather than some complex algorithm

Comment: @Paulie_D no, tags are re-arranged by number of questions. I tagged this question with discussion, dupe-hammer and lastly tags; they were re-arranged because tags has more questions.

Comment: @rene the deleted answer contradicts that. Maybe it selects the first tag entered by the OP.

Comment: See the comments on [this Meta SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268279/234299). They're inconclusive, but it's (reportedly) not based on number of questions in the tag.

Comment: It happened again (http://stackoverflow.com/q/36373434/1771795) I would love to know why?

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't upvote a question complaining about too many gold badges, but that flag. Have an upvote.