# Dupe-hammer reopen question based on the closer's least popular gold tag

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

The intent is simple: the experience in a particular domain should count for something. The more experience you have in a particular topic the more trust you should have to deal with this particular topic.

For example, question has tags: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)[subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess)[pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pexpect). If I have [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) gold badges, I would like to use [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) tag for the dupe hammer because it is more specific (that is, there are fewer questions tagged [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) than there are [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)).

The likelihood of a mistake (the question is not an exact duplicate) is less than it would be for a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) question in general and therefore the reopening of the question *using the dupe hammer* should be restricted to gold badge holders with the same or more specific tag.

For example, for questions closed by a user with a gold badge in [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) or [pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pexpect) in this case, a user with only a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge would only be able to vote for a re-open, and not be able to use their dupe-hammer.

The tag ranking order doesn't have to be exact. If it is precomputed once a year it might be enough. There should be no performance/scaling penalty in this case.

Related: [Dupe hammer: multiple tags, multiple gold badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320062/4279). The current [exact criteria used to choose from multiple tags are unclear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now/268279#comment869603_268279).

> **Q:** do you mean for both closing and reopening to be restricted to only the least popular tag (forbidding the use of the dupehammer to anyone with gold badges only in the other tags), or only for reopening to receive this restriction?

No, only the reopening should be restricted but when you close a question and you have multiple gold badges for the question tags then the least popular is chosen (what tag is chosen has no relation on your ability to close the question)

Comment: So it seems this is technically two related requests: first, locking the reopenhammer so that it can only be swung by someone with the same tag badge as it was closed by (or by any gold badger if it was closed by normal voting/mod w/o gold badge); second, ensuring the dupehammer uses the most restrictive badge possible.

Comment: Do you have some stats or guesses on how many questions/month get hammered by someone with at least two gold badges on that question's tags, how many of those are reopen hammered, and how many of *those* are dubious?

Comment: I think that this is a slightly bigger request than your title makes it out to be, because of the restriction you want on the reopening: right now, unless I'm mistaken , _any_ tag that's present on the question suffices for un-hammering.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: 1- the second is the way to implement the first. If there is no the first one; I don't care about the second one.  2- it is not necessary for the tag to be the same. It just shouldn't be significantly more popular 3- I don't have stats. I don't expect there to be many dubious reopening.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: the least popular tag should win in both directions when closing and reopening using the dupe hammer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I guess I'm not clear, then; do you mean for both closing and reopening to be restricted to only the least popular tag (forbidding the use of the dupehammer to anyone with gold badges only in the other tags), or only for reopening to receive this restriction?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: No, only the reopening should be restricted but when you close a question and you have multiple gold badges for the question tags then the least popular is chosen (what tag is chosen has no relation on your ability to close the question).

Comment: So, on your edit: if you have [python] and [subprocess] gold badges, and you hammer a question with those tags, I _can't reopen_ using my [python] gold badge -- I must have [subprocess]? If that's what you're saying, then that's a change from the way it works now.

Comment: You can't change the question after I've answered it, particularly when it makes my answer seem like it doesn't address the question any more.

Comment: @RobertLongson: could you delete it?

Comment: @RobertLongson: because you misunderstood the question. I didn't change the question I've clarified it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: you can always reopen but the hammer should be used only if you have a gold badge in the question tags with the same (approximately) or less popularity e.g., `[subprocess]`, `[pexpect]`, `[popen]`

Comment: As far as I can see the question makes no sense whatsoever now as it would have no effect on what I could or could not do.

Comment: @RobertLongson I believe it means that, for example, you would not be able to reopen a question that was tagged with both [javascript] and [html] if it was hammered by a user with a gold [html] badge. I think.

Comment: This post might not apply to all tags but still it makes sense. Unjustified/random down-voting doesn't help anyone. A user with JS gold badge doesn't necessarily mean he/she has good commend of any framework/library related to JS. The same applies to all tags which are descending from a main language.

Comment: @MikeM.: if [html] were less popular (significantly) than [javascript] then yes, you wouldn't be able to reopen *using the hammer*—you can still cast one of the five reopen votes. Note: both [javascript] and [html] are ~1e6. In my example, [python] is ~1e6 too while [subprocess] is ~1e3

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, that's pretty much how I read it. I should've said "would not be able to singlehandedly reopen". What metrics are you using, btw? As I see it, [javascript] is nearly twice as popular as [html]. You want a whole order of magnitude, or greater?

Comment: If I use the hammer and the OP says you made a mistake and I agree then I can't correct my mistake.

Comment: @MikeM.  Specific formula for the  tag rank could be  some simple function of the number of questions and/or the number of gold badges (eg., the inverse power law). The intent is that the relative popularity of question's tags  is a proxy for domain expertise (the reverse relation: less popular corresponds to a narrower domain and more experience).

Comment: @RobertLongson that's why you have to use it wisely to avoid such situations. Less popular tags are tricky; users tend to use popular tags to bring more attention.

Comment: @RobertLongson if you use the hammer; you can always undo your own vote.

Comment: @Omar: Labeling downvotes you disagree with on a [tag:feature-request] as "unjustified/random" is baseless, biased language. Just because your evaluation of the feature's value is different does not mean those who disagree with you are voting in bad faith, as that description implies.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If this request doesn't apply to you then justify your _disagreement_.

Comment: @Omar: Downvotes don't necessarily need to be backed by comment-expressed opinions (here, or anywhere), but I'm assuming you somehow missed my comments and answer on this question. Not only do I have justifications, I've detailed them.

Answer (score 11):

Has there been a rash of people using dupe-hammer powers to reopen questions improperly? If not, then I fail to see what problem this solves. It just over-complicates what currently is a very simple construct.

It also seems rather ridiculous to say that you have the power to reopen a question today, but you may not tomorrow depending on how unpopular a particular tag is.

If you have been deemed worthy, then you have been *deemed worthy*.

Comment: 1- One is too many. I've seen thousands of questions; it is irritating then your work is undone. 2- As I said *explicitly* in the question: *"The tag ranking order doesn't have to be exact. If it is precomputed once a year; it might be enough"* i.e., I expect the ranking to be stable and "tomorrow"  in your answer is an exaggeration.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I disagree that one disagreement (and that's what it is - a disagreement, not an objectively incorrect decision, unless the community comes to a consensus on that issue) is a reason to implement a new feature for the entire site. That's a waste of time which could be better spent on more important features or fixes. We haven't even begun to get into the edge cases. Should a C# question be unopenable (with a C# badge) simply because the OP tagged it [tag:git] because they use git (not uncommon!) - and a git gold-tag user incorrectly dupe closed it?

Comment: @Rob: it is all about probabilities. Everybody makes mistakes but a person with more experience in a tag should judge the dupes in this tag better *on average* than a person with less experience. Edge cases may exists but it doesn't matter as long as they are rare. Note: the suggestion doesn't make any question unopenable (you can give one in five votes) i.e., the question may still be opened (with a reduced probability). This reduction is justified by the difference in the experience in a tag.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*it is all about probabilities.*" If you're going to claim probabilities, then you, as the person requesting the feature, ought to be ready to provide some *statistics*. The burden of proof is on you to show why we need it. You haven't proven that edge cases are rare. You haven't provided any evidence that this is even a problem, with questions being incorrectly hammer-reopened. You haven't even shown a *single anecdote* in favor of your proposal. The dupe-hammer was added to solve a proven problem: getting dupes closed faster.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*I expect the ranking to be stable*" If the dupe-hammer rank is not updated to regularly match the actual tag-rankings, then all you're doing is creating confusion. If tags changed ranks between when the post was closed and when someone wanted to reopen it, it's ridiculous to deny someone the power to reopen it when they *ought to have it*, just because the dup-tag-ranking hasn't been updated. If the feature is going to make sense at all, it has to be consistent with the actual, *visible* tag rankings.

Comment: @NicolBolas: 1- on probabilities: [it is common sense.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323331/dupe-hammer-reopen-question-based-on-the-closers-least-popular-gold-tag/323428?noredirect=1#comment346271_323443). 2- on the ranking: you are worrying about imaginary problems. At the level of coarseness that is required for that feature the ranking can be considered constant. The once a year update mentioned in the question is to accommodate outliers.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*on probabilities: it is common sense.*" That's not an example; it is a hypothetical. An example would be an *actual question* which was dupe-hammered, then improperly reopened via dupe-hammer.

Comment: @NicolBolas: if you fall from a big height; there is a high probability that you injure  yourself. I don't need you to jump, to believe the previous statement—it is a common sense.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: 1) You're not describing physics. You're describing social interactions. That's a rather different branch of science, one which is far less hard. 2) You would still be able to show actual examples of people falling from great heights and being injured. As of yet, you have demonstrated exactly zero examples of the phenomenon in question. 3) The "injury" equivalent in your hypothetical is not particularly onerous, so there's not much incentive to stop it. So even if you were to demonstrate that it happened with any real frequency... so what?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: _"you are worrying about imaginary problems."_ Meanwhile, you still haven't mentioned anywhere why the current system is problematic, nor backed it up with evidence that it is.

Comment: @Cerbrus read [the comment on probabilities](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323331/dupe-hammer-reopen-question-based-on-the-closers-least-popular-gold-tag/323428#comment346242_323428). If you don't  understand that a person with more experience makes better decisions regarding things that may require that experience than a person with less experience and therefore the site should reflect that then there is nothing to talk about.

Comment: _"Why wouldn't a python gold badge holder be knowledgeable enough to re-open a question?" ([Source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323331/dupe-hammer-reopen-question-based-on-the-closers-least-popular-gold-tag/323428?noredirect=1#comment346277_323443))_. You have yet to respond to that, @J.F.Sebastian.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Who cares if they can make better decisions? As long as the current people aren't making the *wrong decisions*, then the current system is functional and therefore does not need to change. We don't give a damn about "probabilities"; we want ***FACTS***. And thus far, you have zero facts that there is a problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas: 1- on *"knowledgeable enough"* and *"the current system is functional and therefore does not need to change."*: there are successful phpbb forums and expert-smth-change.com site works to this day. I'm glad founders of Stack Overflow didn't listen to the advice like yours. 2- on FACTS: nobody knows the future but some outcomes are more likely than others. Don't look down on probabilities. The most experimentally verified theory is build on them.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*there are successful phpbb forums and expert-smth-change.com site works to this day. I'm glad founders of Stack Overflow didn't listen to the advice like yours.*" That doesn't even *begin* to make sense. SO wasn't started because some guys had "probabilities" that webforums were a problem. It was started because they had *facts* that they were a problem. They could point to the majority of such sites and show how the lifecycle of them works. This was a well-recognized problem based on genuine facts before SO came along to fix it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*nobody knows the future but some outcomes are more likely than others*" If they were so likely, you wouldn't have to point to probabilities, would you? You would be able to show actual evidence of questions being dupe-reopened improperly. "*Don't look down on probabilities. The most experimentally verified theory is build on them.*" ... No, that's not how science works. Their probabilities are not based on conjecture; they're based on observations of actual reality. You observe *first*, then try to model what you've seen based on probabilities culled from reality.

Comment: ["The true logic of this world is in the calculus of probabilities."—James Clerk Maxwell](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_06.html)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "People who quote great people to make arguments have nothing substantive to say." - Me.

Comment: Follow the link and read the lecture, to avoid  spewing nonsense about science and probabilities.

Answer (score 5):

> For example, for questions closed by a user with a gold badge in [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) or [pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pexpect) in this case, a user with only a [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) gold badge would only be able to vote for a re-open, and not be able to use their dupe-hammer.

Why would this be "better" than the current functionality?

A gold *tag* badge isn't something you just get after a afternoon of answering questions. Gold tag badge holders are knowledgeable about the specific subject.

---

Besides, a restriction like that has the potential for abuse:

Say, user "A" is one of the only users that has a gold badge in [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo). User "B" just got past 2k rep.

A: *"Hey, B, can you add [foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo) to that question, so I can close it?"*
B: *"Sure thing, A!"*

There we go, a question that got closed by *one* user, that takes *5* users to re-open.

---

**tl;dr:** The request isn't *clearly* "better" than the current system, and has the potential for abuse that's harder to undo than it is in the current system.

Comment: "_Gold badge holders are knowledgeable about the specific subject_" incorrect.

Comment: @Omar: Instead of just saying _"You're wrong!"_, Back it up with an explanation. _"Incorrect"_ is not constructive. One does not get a gold badge by just spouting nonsense on SO. The gold badge does not, however, indicate a user is willing to CV as dupe.

Comment: Oh, gold ___tag___ badge holders. I assumed that distinction would've been clear.

Comment: Consider the example in my question: [python] has ~1000000 questions, [subprocess] tag has ~1000 questions. If you have [python] gold badge and I have [subprocess] gold badge and I close [subprocess] question using dupe-hammer. Do you think my vote shouldn't be more binding than yours in this specific case? (you still can vote; just not singlehandedly)

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ a [tag:python] gold badge holder be knowledgeable enough to re-open a question? I can understand that you're more specialized in a question that is tagged with 2 golden tags for you, but what makes you think a user with only one of the tags doesn't have the experience to be able to accurately determine if a question should be re-opened? All you're basically saying is that your experience is being undermined, but you're not explaining _why it's a problem_. The user has a relevant gold tag badge. He didn't get that from a afternoon of screwing around on SO.

Comment: "Gold tag badge holders are knowledgeable about the specific subject." Hmm.. no. I've had people knowledgeable about [tag:jquery] decide to reopen [tag:requirejs] questions that were clearly worthy of being closed to anyone who has expertise in RequireJS. Most gold badge holders are going to acquire their gold badge first through a language tag. Since language tags intersect with a lot of narrower technologies, these holders are very likely to not be knowledgeable about a lot of those technologies that happen to intersect with the one where the system has given them the hammer.

Comment: They usually do have the experience required to recognize a properly closed dupe, though.

Answer (score 4):

This feature request has some problems. It is

- underspecified — some crucial spec details had to be worked out by guesswork, and I'm still not confident I understand it all; for example, what happens if

  - the tag it was dupehammered with is removed from the question?
  - the tag is synonymized with another tag?
  - another, even rarer tag is added that a potential reopener has a gold badge in, or another existing tag becomes rarer?
- overcomplicated — trying to explain even the most basic summary of this in a way that does not sound completely silly or grossly mislead about important implications is very difficult
- unnecessary — no particular argument is presented to give even a rough idea how many questions are benefited by this
- likely to cause many unpleasant side effects — it's obvious that this is designed to reduce question reopens by gold badgers, but at least some reasonable proportion of the reopens to be banned by this are actually correctly reopened, and those will be lost, which hurts the site

The last point, to my mind, is especially important. I don't know what the relative populations of good reopens vs bad vs indifferent vs unaffected are… and probably no one else does either. But it should be obvious that if we are just trading one for one that's not much of a win. If anything, there need to be not just a few more questions reopened that should stay closed that *would* stay closed with this proposal, but **many more** than the questions that should be reopened that *wouldn't* be. And those questions are preventing new answers, which is what the site's about. Without solid argumentation, or preferably hard data, all the complicated spec writing and coding and UI work and docs and testing and so on are so much wasted effort chasing wild geese.

Right now, this is still [-100 in the hole](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/). It's not (yet?) clear that the idea is even *better* than what we've got, never mind worth the hassle.

Comment: 1- about *"underspecified"* -- the details doesn't matter as long as the implementation is true to the spirit of the suggestion (experience should matter; the more experience the more trust) 2- *"overcomplicated"* -- I've updated the question to mention the intent explicitly. 3- *"unnecessary"* -- unjustified statement (it is not about question; it is about people who answer questions and how it affects the site and other questions as a whole). I believe the suggestion should make the site better (a little).

Comment: 4- I assume that a person with vastly more experience in the topic should make better decisions regarding this topic and therefore more questions that should be closed would remain closed and less questions would mistakenly be reopened.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think you've got the burden of proof backwards; a feature *must be actively justified* to exist. Without that... well, there's no point. Ball's in your court to show why this is necessary and significantly better than the status quo. In particular, it's great to require lots of topic expertise to make decisions, but you still need to show that current gold badges aren't doing the job well enough.

Comment: I would expect such an answer from users with at least two gold badges who have faced such situations. Take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17027566/1771795) as an example; it was dupe-closed by a mod. The dupe is has nothing to with the question. I tried reopening with my jquery-mobile gold badge but I couldnt. Yesterday I opened it with jquery gold badge.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: "more experience, more trust" is at the core of the site—there is nothing to proof it is how the site works. The more reputation you have the more the system trusts you. The dupe-hammer itself is the example: you need only one vote instead of five. My suggestion is the natural extension: the more experience you have the more binding your vote is e.g., moderators have the most trust (other than employees perhaps).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Trust levels are extremely coarse-grained, in general, and have largely developed by demonstrating a strong need for particular privileges over time, so no, your new idea of a distinction between two slightly different levels of trustworthiness does *not* automatically prove its superiority, never mind the worth of actually implementing it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: "*The dupe-hammer itself is the example*" But that was *only* created because we needed a way to close duplicates *faster*. Unless people are rapidly and inappropriately unclosing duplicates, your feature doesn't actually solve an existing problem. If you've truly seen this "thousands" of times, it shouldn't be hard for you to gather statistics.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it will work.  Due to the volume of questions, racking up a gold badge in a niche tag is difficult.

But you don't need a gold badge in an obscure feature in order to correctly identify most duplicates - a lot of experience with a particular language is enough.  (except when it isn't of course, but then we can reopen if clarified)

Comment: I don't see how it is relevant. If you don't have the badge; there is no issue to begin with. It is not about identifying duplicates. The feature is about restricting *reopening* singlehandedly if you have much less experience in a given tag then the person who closed it). My feature request makes the hummer the more binding the less popular the question tag you already earned.  The badge is a proxy for the experience in a given tag. The popularity of the tag is a proxy for how wide the domain (a gold badge in a more popular tag should weight less).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: If you have lots of people misinterpreting your feature request, then perhaps you should consider that you have poorly phrased the idea.

Comment: @NicolBolas Their proposal is the second sentence of the post. People just don't spend time reading carefully.

Comment: @NicolBolas: democracy is bad for determining the truth. Look at the quality of the most questions on SO. Should we give up and admit it is the will of the people to have such abysmal questions or should we fight to make the site a little better. Though, as a rule I agree: (paraphrasing the Zen of Python): if the feature is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.