# Which dupe tag shall appear in Mjölnir close vote when I have multiple Mjölnirs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions, dupehammer

Few minutes back, I [CV'd a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37951791/2173917) having both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) tags.

I have Mjölnir for **both** the tags in the **CV'd question**, and the **linked dupe** has **only** the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

I was expecting that the close reason would display [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) in the close reason banner but, to my surprise, [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) showed up.

Now, I do understand (observe) that in the page title, the alphabetically first tag appears, but I was expecting, when I was using Mjölnir, the common tag for the source and the target will be displayed. However, it seems that is not the case.

If my analysis is correct, can I make this a feature request? The request goes like:

> *When using Mjölnir, if the closed question has more than one tag the voter has a gold badge for, then in the linked question:*
>
> - *if only one tag the voter has a gold badge for is present, use that tag in the close reason banner*
> - *if more than one such tag is present, keep using the current alphabetic priority*

Makes sense? Overkill? Any suggestions?

Comment: "Which dupe tag shall appear in Mjölnir close vote when I have multiple Mjölnirs?" Nobody knows. See [Dupe hammer: multiple tags, multiple gold badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320062/176646).

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot and it looks like the tag is chosen based on alphabetic order. So I proposed a modification. Please share your views on the proposal, and Thanks for the link. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver related, but _slightly_ different aspect. :)

Comment: Yup, same problem here with `[javascript]`/`[jquery]`. I fully support this proposal.

Comment: I think we should be able to choose which dupehammer we want to use, or even choose not to use any and only cast a normal vote.

Comment: @Oriol the first  bullet in my proposal. and I did provide an _expectation_ vs _current output_, right? If that's not clear, kindly suggest any improveents in wordings. :)

Comment: Then, if an user has a dupehammer in tags T1 and T2, and votes to close a question Q1 with tag T1 as a duplicate of Q2 with tag T2, you propose to use T2 instead of T1?

Comment: @Oriol Not really, if Q1 has both T1 and T2 and Q2 has T2, then choose T2, not T1.

Comment: Then it makes sense, but I think the proposal is not clear enough. Something like "if only one tag of the closed question the voter has a gold badge for is present in the linked question, use that tag in the close reason banner"

Comment: ...and Q2 *only* has T2. @Oriol, my personal rationale behind this is that when I dupehammer a `[javascript] [jquery]` question (that is basically about jQuery, most of the time) against a `[jquery]` question, I would like `[jquery]` to be displayed in the dupe banner, not `[javascript]`. This adds legitimacy -- just because one is proficient in JavaScript does not mean they're proficient in jQuery either.

Comment: @Oriol feel free to edit, please.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and thanks for the edits. :)

Comment: You're welcome (I don't do that often, and it shows -- Oriol basically got the crux of it in one sentence. Then again, I like bullet points ;)

Comment: @Oriol, I'm afraid I will have to rollback your edit. As I understand it, it's *very* different from the initial proposal (*do not have any golden tags in common, use any golden tag of the former one* or *use any of the common golden tags* do not click). Your previous comment was way more on-target. Sourav, do you agree?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, I'd go with you. :)

Comment: @Oriol To elaborate, it'll be very rare case, when "do not have any golden tags in common" for dupes, rather the most obvious scenarios will be, more than one golden tag in common, don't you agree?

Comment: If my edit wasn't right then I'm sorry but I don't understand the request :( What should happen in the rare case where there is no golden common tag?

Comment: @Oriol sir, in case there is no golden common tag, it'll be the common tag, even if no common, then the golden in the to-be closed one will be default, correct?

Comment: @Oriol If there is any more confusion, can we please discuss it tomorrow? It's already 3:30 am here, i need to go to bed...

Comment: Of course... Good night

Comment: In the case that the target question does not have a common tag with which a gold tag badge is held by the close voter, fall back to whatever the current selection process is.

Answer (score 10):

**No. Rather list *all relevant gold badges of the hammering user.*** I suggest the following algorithm:

- if the intersection of post tags, hammer target tags and user gold badges is not an empty set, then show *all* badges in that set.
- else, show *all badges* in the intersection of post tags and user gold badges.

e.g. given that the user has a gold badge in both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays), and the duplicate question is tagged with both [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays),

- and the target is tagged with only [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), display *only [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)*, as it seems to be the truly relevant one.
- if the question is tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) and **the *target* is tagged with them both, display them both too.**
- if the target does not have *either of these 2 tags*, *then* in the face of ambiguity refuse the temptation to guess, and display *both* [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) again.

This, besides the possible database schema change to support multiple gold badges, would be rather trivial to implement and would not need a UI change.

---

Consider for example [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) vs [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) - as SQLAlchemy is a library written solely for Python, there is *no* conceivable SQLAlchemy question that wouldn't have to be tagged  with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) too. Corollary, there is no one with the SQLAlchemy gold badge that would not also have received the Python gold badge from **these same posts alone**. A correctly tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) question that is *not* about a typo, but is a worthy duplicate, quite often is hammered to another [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) question.

Gold in [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) is what truly gives one the authority to identify the duplicates for questions about that behemoth library with its own peculiarities, not just generic knowledge of Python. However,

```
>>> 'python' < 'sqlalchemy'
True
```

and the fact that set of [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlalchemy) questions that do not belong to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is ∅ means that the merit of having gold badge in SQLAlchemy would not be ever acknowledged.

Answer (score 5):

This remains a problem 3 years later.

I get the same [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) gold badge tag in close reasons. This is unfortunate, since "arrays" is mostly a language agnostic crap tag and not really one that should give particular privileges. The post should be closed because of a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) gold badge and nothing else.

I think this is a strange and unintended side effect of the dupe hammer system. It is confusing for the OP to get their question closed by some "array badger". It could potentially be abused. It turns even more questionable on meta, where some "master of [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)" can single-handedly kill any discussion they personally don't like.

To solve this I think we should only grant dupe hammer behavior to a list of selected tags, with some sort of way to apply for "dupe hammerable status" for a tag.

Specifically, only things that require domain knowledge should have dupe hammerable tags. Such as tags for programming languages, libraries or tools.

Comment: If you *do* have a gold badge for something like arrays, wouldn't that mean you're in a better position to be able to moderate and deal with duplicated questions in regards to arrays across domains?  Or is this more of a case that you don't trust someone with that kind of power?

Comment: Should a C coder with the arrays badge hammer a Python Numpy array question? Probably not, unless they also have Python gold.

Comment: Arrays as concept is rarely relevant in a programming language. Each language has it own set of characteristics. That you've answered many questions about arrays in one language, you aren't very likely to be able to answer in any other language. I prefer such tags to not exist.

Comment: @Braiam:  So that again goes to a level of trust - either with the gold-badge holder trusting themselves to make that call, or the community trusting the gold-badge holder to make that call.  I'd imagine that if someone got the arrays tag on answering nothing but Java questions, they wouldn't get a wild hair and decide to answer questions about [arrays in PostgreSQL](https://heap.io/blog/engineering/dont-iterate-over-a-postgres-array-with-a-loop), given how fundamentally different they are.

Comment: @Makoto the thing is that they will not be able to do the call if the questions that arrays *as concept* aren't the main topic of the question. I think we would be hard pressed in finding a question that needs the array tag at all. I've touched this topic before https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066

Comment: @Braiam:  Try your luck with a burnination request of the array tag, then.

Comment: So, wouldn't it be nice if it said [**Single-handedly hammered by awesome Lundin |●c| |●arrays|**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382770/918959)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That's a good idea indeed. Just match all tags in the question with the user's gold badges.

Comment: Or question*s*...